# Codeigniter rewriting URLs

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting

How should a hook be written to have a segment appended URL when a url pattern is matched?

**For example:**

```
/site/product/id
```

**Routes to:**

```
/site/product/id/title-from-query
```

Comment: so you need /site/product/id redirect to /site/product/id/title-from-query ?

Comment: thats it, what I probably should of asked is, should I be putting queries inside CI's routes.php?

Comment: by query, do you mean an SQL query, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested in your comment, Codeigniter's routes are perfect for this. They allow you to control exactly what a user/browser can see in the URL while pushing that through to something meaningful to the framework.

In your routes.php, you would need something like:

```
$route['site/product/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'controller/method/$1';
$route['site/product/(:num)] = 'controller/method/$1';
```

In the first line, the second parameter `(:any)` is just there to allow the route to accept the `title-from-query`, the second line is optional and is there to handle the case that no `title-from-query` has been specified. `'controller/method'` should be replaced with the name of your controller and the method being used.

**Update:**

To create these URLs (if you don't already have a slug in the database), you can use the [`url_title()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) method:

```
echo anchor('site/product/id'.url_title($title));
```

The above would create a link with the 'slug' on the end. To force the redirect, you would need to check that the correct segment has been set in your controller and then redirect if it hasn't. StackOverflow's implementation is most likely for SEO purposes, if you remove the slug, you get taken to an address with the slug and it must use the ID to figure out what it is. You would need the same logic to redirect if the slug hasn't been supplied:

```
redirect('/site/product/id/'.$slug, 'location', 301);
```

Comment: sorry, what I meant was the site/product/id would have a title-from-query appended to the resulting url. The reason I'm doing this is so the user always sees a product with a url in the form of /site/product/id/title-from-query. You'll notice if you try stackoverflow.com/questions/id it appends the title to the end so I thought this would be good practice.

Comment: updated my answer with more details on what you would need to do and how you could approach it.

Comment: Dear cchana, Excellent job done by you. Thanks it helps me a lot.